# webpack url loader doesn't load jpg image

Tags: webpack, urlloader

I have some problems importing jpg images with webpack and url-loader.
Here's my webpack config:

```
const common = {
  entry: path.join(PATHS.src, 'index.tsx'),
  output: {
    path: PATHS.build,
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js"]
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        loader: "ts-loader",
        exclude: /node_modules/
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['env', 'react']
          }
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|woff|woff2|ttf|mp3)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: {
              limit: 1000000
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    ],
  }
};
```

And i try to import jpg image like this:`import * as map from '../../../i/map.jpg';`
And i got an error here from webpack: TS2307: Cannot find module '../../../i/map.jpg'.
Still, the applications is working after the build, and "corrupted" image is displayed.
Btw, a png image from the same folder as jpg image working fine, no error during build. 
Can you help me? What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

well i didn't manage to solve the problem with importing jpg image, but i found a solution replacing import with require. Still I have no idea what wrong with my config or webpack itself.